# How to securely gather multiple servers data for monitoring

Tags: security, monitoring, network-monitoring, system-monitoring, reporting

I got an 'admin' server where all admin GUI can be accessed.
I also have 2 other servers, 1 web and 1 db. As I expand for a nodejs server/api, I was wondering how could I transfer servers information to my admin server.

Possibilities I found so far:

**Scenario 1**

- Make all servers generate jsons files with a `top` output for example in a compressed file, encrypted.
- Admin server connect to the remote server through ssh/sftp and grab that file every hour.

Pros: easy to implement, cons: not real time at all

**Scenario 2**

- Install nodejs+socketio on every servers and connect to admin server to send/receive data

Pros: realtime, easy to maintain, Cons: security risks?, may have multiple servers daemon running on every servers, increase vulnerability. Harder to implement?

I never implement such a thing and I know there is aio bundle for that but the issue is that it amkes it harder to modify since you didn't code it. Or maybe there is a magical tool I didn't heard of?

Thanks for your inputs.

OS used: Debian 8 and Ubuntu 16.04
Servers: Nginx/Php, Nodejs/ES6, RethinkDb, MariaDB, Redis
Locations: USA NL

Comment: What kind of information do you want to "grab" ? As you are talking about top, maybe cpu / ram / processes ? There is plenty of tool to do this and a couple are really famous...

Comment: Yes, cpu, ram, port status, process status, general monitoring. Tools I found generally are hard to integrate or just doesn't seem to fit. Any suggestions?

Comment: I use grafana with telegraf and influx db, and it's possible to have many data. Check the playground on the grafana site to have an idea